# I am trying to retrieve users information from Azure active directory using Microsoft Graph api from java code but i am getting 400 error(Bad request)

Tags: java, http, microsoft-graph-api, httpurlconnection, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve users information from Azure active directory using Microsoft Graph api from java code but i am getting 400 error(Bad request) , but it works well in postman .

The java code with which i am working is

```
    String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=displayName eq 'Dasari Siri'";
    String token = "Bearer "+accesstoken; 
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();  
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
    con.connect();
    StringBuffer Response = new StringBuffer();
    if(con!=null){
    try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));        String input ;
           while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
             Response.append(input);
           }
           br.close();
               }              
           catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
```

The error which I am getting is

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=displayName eq 'Dasari Siri'
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.javatpoint.Downloadcsv.doDownloadCsv(Downloadcsv.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

[The postman request which worked fine for me is :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgL69.png)

Can you please go through this and let me know where i am making mistake

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please encode the filter part of your url and try again ?

Comment: @HuryShen thanks for your suggestion, I am very new to this can you please let me know how to do this in  short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the encode for the filter part of the url and add a line to set property "Accept" as "application/json"). Please refer to my code below:

```
public class Testgraph {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?" + URLEncoder.encode("$filter=displayName eq 'huryTest'", "UTF-8");
        String token = "Bearer " + "your access token"; 
        URL obj = new URL(url);

        HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();  
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        StringBuffer Response = new StringBuffer();
        if(con!=null){
        try {
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));        
              String input ;
               while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                 Response.append(input);
                 System.out.print("---------success------");
               }
               br.close();
                   }              
               catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @HuryShen it's working , but i am having a small issue hope you can help me with it the thing is i am getting the information of all the users , instead of getting the details of specified user only

Comment: Yeah i had figured it out ,  the url should be changed as                                            `String url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users$filter="+URLEncoder.encode("displayName eq 'huryTest'", "UTF-8");`